# Function to increase X by Y while keeping its negative or positive value

Tags: functions

I hope my question is not too dumb.

I need to make a function that adds Y to X towards its sign.
I know I'm probably not very clear, so here is an example.

If X = -3 and Y is 2, the results is -5.
If X = 2 and Y is 4, the results is 6.

Is there a function to do that ?

Answer (score 3):

This function is not going to be continuous.  So, it'll need to be defined piecewise (or something equivalent to piecewise).

Something like this would do:
$$f(x,y)=
\begin{cases}
x-|y| & \text{if } x<0 \\
x+|y| & \text{if } x>0 \\
x & \text{if } x=0.
\end{cases}$$

This equivalent to $$f(x,y)=x+|y|\ \mathrm{sng}(x)$$ where $\mathrm{sgn}$ denotes the [sign function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_function).

Comment: You might consider replacing $2$ by $y$ or $|y|$ (it is unclear from the examples in the question) as your function does not work when $y=4$.

Comment: Thank you for that; I've made the change.

Comment: Thanks, so there is no other way of doing it beside testing x. I thought there might have been some math operator that would keep me from doing it.

Comment: Well, the operator would be $x \mapsto x+|y|\ \mathrm{sng}(x)$.  (But, I don't see how it could be possible to find the value a function would return, say the function $x \mapsto x^2$, without knowing what $x$ is.  We just write $x^2$.)